Visual Studio Code switch to wrong header if name is engine.cpp
In my C++ projects I often use a class called Engine so its files are engine.h and engine.cpp. In Visual Studio Code I can use the shortcut Alt + O to switch between the header and the source code.
It happens that if I'm editing my engine.cpp file, it switches to engine.hpp inside:

/home/mark/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/asio/asio/asio/include/asio/ssl/detail/engine.hpp

Why it does not switch to the existing header engine.h that is in the include directory of my project? It's very annoying! Is there a way to fix this odd behavior that is not like "renaming your files to something else".

its a long standing bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2635

As user @Alan Birtles pointed out, it is a bug. In the link provided by the comment, there is also a workaround:

Meanwhile, the workaround I found to this issue is to install the extension c-mantic and bind the shortcut to its "Switch Header Source". It seems to work correctly.

